# Avoid Angular/TypeScript variable binding

Tags: angular, data-binding, variable-binding

I need to create a clone of my object, without creating it's reference.
When I try to copy EquipmentClass, witch is my main object to it's clone,
and if I change some property of EquipmentClass it will change my EquipmentClassCloneEdit also. And I don't want that to happen.

I tried to assign the value like this:

```
this.equipmentClassCloneEdit = Object.assign({}, this.equipmentClass);
```

this is my model:

```
export class EquipmentClass {
    equipmentClassId: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    isDeleted: boolean;
    propertyValuesList: EquipmentClassPropertyValue[] = [];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `this.equipmentClassCloneEdit = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.equipmentClass))`

`Object.assign()` creates a shallow copy, so it wouldn't work on non-primitives like your propertyValuesList array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash's cloneDeep method to do a deep clone.
https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep

1. install 'lodash' package
2. `import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';`
3. just call it: `this.equipmentClassCloneEdit = cloneDeep(this.equipmentClass);`

Using this kind of cloning functions is better from stringify and then parse solution as it also keeps members which JSON ingores when stringifying, like, Functions, Symbols, BigInts etc.